# Python перенести столбцы в строки

Tags: python, таблицы

Есть таблица, где в столбик указаны тысячи названий групп и наименования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи python можно перенести наименования в строку, как показана на примере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кол-во наименований в каждой группе разное.

Comment: А что такое "таблица" в питоне ? Может она у вас в базе данных ? тогда можно попробовать выбрать данные из базы примерно в том виде как вы хотите, а в питоне только чуть доделать. Если это не так, то в питоне создаем пустой словарь, бежим по исходному массиву и в словарь питона с ключом по первой колонке данных кладем массив в который добавляем очередной элемент из второй колонки. По завершении пробегаемся по словарю и выводим ключ и и все накопленные значения из массива

Comment: Непонятно, зачем это вообще нужно? Таблица по определению предполагает что-то такое прямоугольное. А у вас получается будет разное кол-во элементов в строках, таблица получится "зубчатая" и очень широкая. Кому это нужно? Или это просто учебное задание?

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов решения задачи много. Но вы столь небрежно сформулировали свой вопрос -  что просто непонятно, чего вы ходите. Раз уж ваш вопрос помечен тегом Python, то надо было представить данные не в виде картики, взятой кстати кажется из EXCEL, а в том виде, в котором они у вас в программе. Но раз вы этого не сделали -  даю собственный пример, а уж под свою задачу теперь подгоняйте его сами.
Итак:
Исходный датафрейм:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Что':['Автомобили','Автомобили','Автомобили',
                        'Животные','Животные'],'Кто':['Ford','VW','GM','Кот','Собака']})
```

Выглядит он разумеется вот так:

```
Out[21]: 
          Что     Кто
0  Автомобили    Ford
1  Автомобили      VW
2  Автомобили      GM
3    Животные     Кот
4    Животные  Собака
```

Варианты ответов.

1.

```
df.groupby('Что')['Кто'].apply(list)
```

Результат:

```
Out[22]: 
Что
Автомобили    [Ford, VW, GM]
Животные       [Кот, Собака]
Name: Кто, dtype: object
```

2. 

```
df.groupby('Что').agg({'Кто':lambda x: list(x)})
```

Результат:

```
Оut[23]: 
                       Кто
Что                       
Автомобили  [Ford, VW, GM]
Животные     [Кот, Собака]
```

3. 

```
df.groupby('Что').agg(pd.Series.tolist)
```

Результат:

```
Out[24]: 
                       Кто
Что                       
Автомобили  [Ford, VW, GM]
Животные     [Кот, Собака]
```

4. df.groupby('Что').agg(Кто=('Кто','unique'))

Результат:

```
Out[27]: 
                       Кто
Что                       
Автомобили  [Ford, VW, GM]
Животные     [Кот, Собака]
```

5. pd.Series({x : y.Кто.tolist() for x , y in df.groupby('Что')})

Результат:

```
Out[28]: 
Автомобили    [Ford, VW, GM]
Животные       [Кот, Собака]
dtype: object
```

Выбирайте.